# dataweave xml namespace declarations at root element

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have a dataweave script that produces some xml.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"
%namespace soap http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope
%namespace ns http://www.mycompany/2015/07

---
{
    soap#Envelope: {
        soap#Header: {
        },
        soap#Body: {
            ns#GetVehDetails: {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It produces something like this...

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Header/>
  <soap:Body>
    <ns:GetVehDetails xmlns:ns="http://www.mycompany/2015/07">
```

How can I change the dataweave script to output the xml namespace declarations at the root element:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
               xmlns:ns="http://www.mycompany/2015/07">
  <soap:Header/>
  <soap:Body>
    <ns:GetVehDetails>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old Dataweave issue and the only way it can be solved as following:
You need to add a dummy attribute `@(ns#name:"")` with the namespace that you want to be at top in the top most root tag such as `Envelope` tag in this case

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"
%namespace soap http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope
%namespace ns http://www.mycompany/2015/07

---
{
    soap#Envelope @(ns#name:""): {
        soap#Header: {
        },
        soap#Body: {
            ns#GetVehDetails: {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks! Is this a fail safe solution or is there any traps I need to know about?

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary this solution also includes ns:name="" attribute along with the first one. Any solution for that?

Comment: This is required to bring the namespace at the top at Envelope level ..  This is actually a flaw in Dataweave and this way you can bring all the namespace at top root element... you can give any attribute there instead of ns#name ... This is just a dummy attribute.. This is currently only the trick and you cannot skip that dummy attribute ..

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"
%namespace soap http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope
%namespace ns http://www.mycompany/2015/07
---
{
    soap#Envelope @("xmlns:ns":'http://www.mycompany/2015/07'): {
        soap#Header: {
        },
        soap#Body: {
            ns#GetVehDetails: {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nope, you will get a separate namespace definition on `GetVehDetails` anyway.

Comment: that's an invalid dw script

Comment: Its invalid on the transform message, try to run it